# How to present multiple PNG images as GIF in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, png

I studying a wpf project.
I have 40 PNG files with transparent backgrounds, and when I stitch them together, they work like a natural loading bar. I don't want to make it into a GIF, but rather like loading something into the UI in PNG format.

The attempts I've made are as follows:

1. Repetitive implementation using UI Thread: I found a huge consumption of resources. It is considered unsuitable.
2. WpfAnimatedGif library: It is considered inappropriate to use the desired 40 PNG files.

If you have any good ideas, please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have in your XAML an `Image` element named `image` and your paths to the png files in a `List<string>` named `imagePaths` you can use a timer:

```
private void UpdateLoadingBar()
{
    var frameIndex = 0;
    var frameCount = imagePaths.Count;
        
    var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        loadingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(
            new Uri(imagePaths[frameIndex], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        if (++frameIndex >= frameCount)
        {
            // Stop the timer when all frames have been displayed
            timer.Stop();
        }
    };

    timer.Start();
}
```

Or if you are familiar with async programming you could use

```
private async Task UpdateLoadingBar()
{
    foreach (var imagePath in imagePaths)
    {
        loadingImage.Source = new BitmapImage(
            new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        // Delay between each frame (adjust the duration as needed)
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

This needs to be started from an async event handler like:

```
private async void StartLoadingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await UpdateLoadingBar();
}
```

Comment: The loop with Thread.Sleep won't work. It will simply block the UI thread until its done. Never use Thread.Sleep in the UI thread.

Comment: Also be aware trhat BitmapImage has a constructor that takes an Uri argument. No need to call BeginInit and EndInit.

Comment: There is also no need for Dispatcher.Invoke here. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for providing a good solution.
Let's try based on that solution.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for your edits and suggestions!

Comment: @user18501010 Loading of all the BitmapImages could be done in a background thread to relieve the UI thread from this potentially time consuming task. Let us know if the performance is acceptable.

Comment: @Clemens System performance is judged to be adequate. Since the storage device uses SSD, I think there will be no problem with IO performance to load media files.

Comment: First, I applied the solution provided above.
It showed better resource utilization than the way I applied it. thank you.
I will try to optimize the above code once.
Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: @user18501010 Depending on the size of the original PNGs, you may also try to set the BitmapImage's DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight to reduce resolution and hence resource consumption.

Comment: @Clemens Then, it would be a good idea to properly change the resolution of the prepared image resource. It reminds me of when I was configuring Android's Drawble.
thanks for the great idea